# Model is null when form submitted to Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have a simple Edit page. When I initialize the Edit Page it is working properly(call the service and bind ViewModel to textboxes properly).

But if I want to submit the form again it gives me the null Album object in AlbumViewModel in the Edit Action method. (I have added screenshot)
[image]
ViewModel :

```
        public class AlbumViewModel
        {
            public Album Album { get; set; }
        }
```

Action :

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(AlbumViewModel album)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                this._albumService.UpdateAlbum(album);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

cshtml :

```
@model Musicalog.Application.ViewModels.AlbumViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}
<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm(Html.BeginForm("Edit", null, FormMethod.Post, null)))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Album.AlbumID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Album.AlbumName)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Album.Artist)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Album.Stock)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.Album.Type)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Album.AlbumName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Album.AlbumName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Album.AlbumName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Album.AlbumName)

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Paramater name '**album**' that you have use that have **similar to** the model.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(AlbumViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                this._albumService.UpdateAlbum(model);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

and also you can remove null from html.BeginForm

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Html.BeginForm("Edit", null, FormMethod.Post)))
```